# How to pause my application's audio/music after launching google's Voice Search (Speech Recognition)?

Tags: android, search, voice, audio-player

I made an Audio-Player and I need to pause it when the user launches google Voice Search.

I just tried 2 ways, but all failed

1. Write an receiver to receive broadcast action intent
   "android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH", but it doesn't work at all, can not receive callback from Voice Search.
2. Write a service to get SpeechRecognizer, as following, (partial of my codes)

code:

```
  public class VoiceSearchMonitor extends Service
  {
      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate()
      {
        // Get SpeechRecognizer
        SpeechRecognizer recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);

        // Create a new RecognitionListener
        RecognitionListener listener = new RecognitionListener()
        {
           @Override
           public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) 
           {
              // *** I want to pause my audio here ***
           }     

           @Override
           public void onEndOfSpeech()
           {
              // *** I want to resume my audio here ***
           }
        }

        // make an intent
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH");

        // Start listening
        recognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
        recognizer.startListening(intent);
      }
   }
```

Just can not receive the callback `onReadyForSpeech`, 'onEndOfSpeech' after I launch Voice Search, so there's no way for me to pause my audio. I just wonder if there is a way to get SpeechRecognizer instance of google's Voice Search, so that I can get the callback correctly??

Does anyone know the answer to my question? Thanks for helping!!!

Joy

Answer (score 1):

I took the same route initially for this issue, but the solution is to use the AudioManager rather than the SpeechRecognizer.

Our app was already using a custom listener for AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener and was correctly responding to the AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN and AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS states.  It turns out that the voice search triggers an AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT state, so adding that to the change listener resulted in playback being paused while the voice search was performed.

To summarize:

**Create the listener**

```
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener audioFocusListener = 
    new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        Logging.d(TAG, "audiofocus change");
        if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS || focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT)
            suspendPlayback();
        if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
            resumePlayback();
    }
};
```

**Get the AudioManager, request focus, and pass the listener**

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```